# Error while running Jmeter Perfmon

Tags: jmeter, performance

```
PS C:\Users\sebin.vincent> e:
PS E:\> .\Softwares\ServerAgent-2.2.3\startAgent.bat
INFO    2019-12-30 12:17:45.122 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding UDP to 4444
INFO    2019-12-30 12:17:45.155 [kg.apc.p] (): Binding TCP to 4444
INFO    2019-12-30 12:17:45.157 [kg.apc.p] (): JP@GC Agent v2.2.3 started
INFO    2019-12-30 12:18:59.180 [kg.apc.p] (): Accepting new TCP connection
INFO    2019-12-30 12:18:59.184 [kg.apc.p] (): Yep, we received the 'test' command
INFO    2019-12-30 12:18:59.187 [kg.apc.p] (): Starting measures: memory:       cpu:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000010014ed4, pid=19028, tid=3160
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (11.0.4+10) (build 11.0.4+10-LTS)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.4+10-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [sigar-amd64-winnt.dll+0x14ed4]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# E:\\hs_err_pid19028.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

I can't find a possible solution, even after vast range of search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're suffering from the same problem as it's described in [Sigar 1.6.4 is crashing: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405832/sigar-1-6-4-is-crashing-exception-access-violation), one of the reasons I can think of is that [Windows PerfMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/perfmon) doesn't have CPU counters enabled so [SIGAR](https://github.com/hyperic/sigar) fails to read this information and causes JVM crash due to a bug in its native `sigar-amd64-winnt.dl`

Try inspecting Windows PerfMon settings and ensure that CPU telemetry is enabled.

It might also be the case your account doesn't have enough permissions to collect CPU information from Windows performance counters, try [running ServerAgent as administrator](https://www.itechtics.com/run-programs-administrator/)

As the last resort you could consider switching to [SSHMon](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon) plugin which doesn't rely on SIGAR and doesn't require Server Agent to be running on the machine you want to monitor. Check out [How to Monitor Server Resource Utilization with JMeter’s SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener/) article for more details if needed.

Comment: Thanks guys for this valuable input, it looks like Perfmon does not work anymore with version jdk1.8.0_251 and higher version for Windows Machines, not sure about Linux though.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Install jdk1.8.0_241
2. configure jdk1.8.0_241 with JAVA_HOME
3. Restart your server agent

Your Error will resolve after performing above steps.

Comment: Please clarify step 2 on how to configure JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Can you explain why this problem has occurred?

Comment: @SebinVincent
-> Java version issue because latest Java version doesn't support so it's bug from Java Oracle side.
-> sigar-amd64-winnt.dll is also not updated from many year so that dll support only jdk1.8.0_241 version

Comment: @Prome Follow below URL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270314/setting-java-home-in-windows